# Android Inventory App with Photos, Cloud Storage and Report

Tags: android, inventory

User Story:

- We need a mobile application for Android to manage products. We need it for uploading photos and a few data fields. Report printing with photos is also wanted. Finally, the application should store the data on its server.

Basic Features:

- Extra Fields Customization
- Inventory Item with Photos
- Secure storage on the cloud
- Report generation with Photo
- One Photo Per Item

My Budget:

- Free to 100$US

How Many Items:

- Many (100 Items / Day)

Number of Kinds of Items:

- One

Comment: If you could add a little "user story" (i.e. what you intend to do with it), it might help to give better recommendations. From what you've currently put, even Flickr might be a match ;)

Comment: What is your budget? Are you OK with advertisement? How many items? How many kinds of item? One photo per kind of item, right, not one photo per item?